# Way to convert Iterator to mutable List in Java using `apache-commons`, `guava` or some other popular library

Tags: java, guava, apache-commons

Is there any `magicMethod` working like this:

```
List<E> resultList = magicMethod((Iterator<E>)inputIterator);
```

NB: `resultList` should be mutable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [Lists#newArrayList(Iterator)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList-java.util.Iterator-).

Comment: But, watch out for functional programmers who create Iterators for *infinite lists*.